# Dreamweaver can't connect to localhost

Tags: browser, xampp, localhost, dreamweaver

I can't preview what I'm programming in Dreamweaver in any browser anymore.
The message I get (e.g. from Safari) is: Safari can't open the page "localhost/~user/mySite/index.htm", Safari can't connect to the server "localhost"

I just couldn't find any answers in the internet which could solve this.

What I did since the last time it still worked, was installing xampp and setting up a local server.

With servers stopped, I get the message above, when MySQL, ProFTPD and Apache are started, I get the following message:
"Object not found" and "Error 404".

Any help would be much appreciated, I really don't know what to do!

Thanks a lot, Ollie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This path `"localhost/~user/mySite/index.htm` does not look correct.

Usually on XAMPP goes as follows.

If I consider that your files are located in a "mySite" folder inside htdocs and an index.html exists then you can access them by typing on the browser `localhost/mySite`.

Note:

Turn on Apache, and MySQL if you are using a database.

Comment: Thanks a lot Makis, your post sums it up pretty much.

I actually didn't have the folder in htdocs, that's why it didn't work.

All the the steps for Dreamweaver can be followed here:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NtaX9WJMgvk

If you're not creating a new site, but couldn't preview current sites in Dreamweaver anymore, all you need to do is make the changes from the video in "manage sites" instead of "new site".

That's it, worked perfect for me!